Compress any numbers of warning messages into one
From ?options, the description of warn said

If 10 or fewer warnings were signalled, they will be printed, otherwise a message saying how many were signalled.

So if there are more than 10 warnings, they will be compressed into 1 message. For example:
f <- function() {
  warning("warn 1")
  warning("warn 2")
  warning("warn 3")
  warning("warn 4")
  warning("warn 5")
  warning("warn 6")
  warning("warn 7")
  warning("warn 8")
  warning("warn 9")
  warning("warn 10")
  warning("warn 11")
  return(1)
}

f()


[1] 1 
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

How can I reduce the limit of 10 to 1? I.e. Even if I have only one warning, I expect it to show

There were 1 warnings (use warnings() to see them)


See also this old thread for similar discussion   https://www.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-September/079494.html

Couldn't find an option to globally set this threshold to a custom value (might be a nice feature request you could discuss on r-devel). Instead, you could use a wrapper function to summarize warnings where needed. We'd need an environment since---for good reason---'last.warning' is read-only.
W <- \(FUN) {
  env <- new.env()
  env$w_lst <- list()  ## empty warning list to increment
  res <- withCallingHandlers(FUN, warning=\(w) {
    env$w_lst <- c(env$w_lst, list(w))
    invokeRestart('muffleWarning')
  })
  n <- length(env$w_lst)  ## count warnings
  if (n > 0) {
    more <- (n > 1L) + 1L
    msg <- sprintf('There %s %s warning%s (use warnings2() to see %s)',
                   switch(more, 'was', 'were'),
                   n,
                   switch(more, '', 's'),
                   switch(more, 'it', 'them')
    )
    message('Warning: ', msg)
    assign('last.warning', env$w_lst, envir=warn_env)  ## assign warnings to env
  }
  res
}
## alternative warnings function
warnings2 <- \() {
  if (exists("last.warning", envir=warn_env)) {
    w_lst <- get("last.warning", envir=warn_env)
    for (i in seq_along(w_lst)) {
      message(sprintf('Warning %d: %s', i, conditionMessage(w_lst[[i]])))
    }
  } else {
    base::warnings()
  }
}


> warn_env <- new.env()  ## create env for 'last.waning'
> 
> W(f(0))
[1] 1
> W(f(1))
Warning: There was 1 warning (use warnings2() to see it)
[1] 1
> W(f(2))
Warning: There were 2 warnings (use warnings2() to see them)
[1] 1
> W(f(11))
Warning: There were 11 warnings (use warnings2() to see them)
[1] 1
> 
> warnings2()
Warning 1: foo
Warning 2: foo
Warning 3: foo
Warning 4: foo
Warning 5: foo
Warning 6: foo
Warning 7: foo
Warning 8: foo
Warning 9: foo
Warning 10: foo
Warning 11: foo


Data:
f <- \(n) {
  replicate(n, warning('foo'))
  return(1)
}


I wonder: possibly one could create a code expression  for warning.expression and , combined with options(warn = -1)  , collect the warning messages separately?  Or would that second step clear warnings before warning.expression could collect the info?

Add to my previous comment -- it looks like that won't work without using <<- , which is highly risky.

@CarlWitthoft Actually was trying warn=1, however at some point it felt like a deadlock,  as it not only suppresses warnings, but there are actually no more warnings. So I came up with this.

@CarlWitthoft Always feel like dancing with the devil using <<-, but it only assigns in parent, right? So not quite sure why it's so taboo.

It's not allowed in CRAN packages (among other things) because it can clobber an existing object in  the console environment.    I'm in the camp that says no function should be able to do anything outside its own environment other than returning an object.

@CarlWitthoft Ah, I didn't know that. Then we should better assign to a  new.env() in the function. Thanks, edited.
